# How to search a string and return only numeric value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, charindex, patindex

I need to create a formula column. In this column I need to return a numeric value.

Example:

database.dbo.table1 has a column called "message" that contains a long message.

The message is formatted as so: `various words, characters, spaces <this document is> document# = 12345 <this document is>`

What I need to do is search through the message, find "this document is" and searched between both of those phrases for the numeric value of the document, return the document # inside the formula column.

Comment: It seems like you know some of the functions based on the tags `charindex` and `patindex` but you haven't included any attempts at solving it. You should really include some of your attempts, and explain why they didn't work.

Comment: @bluefeet I dont really know the functions. Ive searched and come across them a lot but cant figure out how to correctly use them to solve my problem. So I have attempted anything yet because I honestly dont know where to start.

Comment: @G.Colon You start on the Microsoft documentation pages for those functions.

Comment: Is that an XML?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Yes it is.

Comment: Could you supply a valid sample?

Comment: @everyone Im just not understand how charindex is used. It returns the position of something. That information is useless to me. I dont need to know where the 4 is located. I need to know the entire numeric value. I'm very new to SQL so this is why my question is posted.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz the only thing I can provide is this <SendDocument DocumentID="1234567">true</SendDocument>

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I need to basically find SendDocument and search between the 2 phrases to acquire the numeric value

Comment: @G.Colonm, I wrote you an answer. As for string functions in SQL Server - I still can't believe that this is what Microsoft supplies to its users. Nothing is trivial in doing the most simple text manipulations in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQLXML XQuery functions/methods (e.g. doc.value() is generally expensive and should be avoided when possible. In this case, based on the information provided, you can get what you need using [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If you are working with a (n)varchar field you could do this:

```
declare @mytab table (doc varchar(max))    
insert into @mytab values ('<SendDocument DocumentID="1234567">true</SendDocument>');

SELECT SUBSTRING(ci,1,CHARINDEX('"',ci)-1)
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(doc, CHARINDEX('DocumentID="',doc)+12,20) FROM @mytab) start(ci);
```

If you are working with an XML field you could do this:

```
declare @mytab table (doc xml); 
insert into @mytab values ('<SendDocument DocumentID="1234567">true</SendDocument>');

SELECT SUBSTRING(ci,1,CHARINDEX('"',ci)-1)
FROM 
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING
    (
      CAST(doc AS varchar(max)), 
      CHARINDEX('DocumentID="', CAST(doc AS varchar(max)))+12,
      20
    )
  FROM @mytab
) start(ci);
```

Comment: that gets me close as well! Thank you. Im trying to break it down and understand it

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @mytab table (doc xml)    
insert into @mytab values ('<SendDocument DocumentID="1234567">true</SendDocument>')

select      doc.value('(//@DocumentID)[1]','int')
from        @mytab
```

---

If it is not saved as XML but as VARCHAR

```
declare @mytab table (doc varchar(max))    
insert into @mytab values ('<SendDocument DocumentID="1234567">true</SendDocument>')

select      cast (doc as xml).value('(//@DocumentID)[1]','int')
from        @mytab
```

Comment: Thank you. That will get me started.